# Why threading.stack_size() does not produce the effect wanted?

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, networking

I am using Python 2.7 x86 on Windows 7 x64. I would like to stick with Python 2.7 for x86 for now as the applications I code will be used on mostly x86 machines anyway.

Right now, the script I am working on, works fine at around 700 threads. I am using a Queue.
The need for more threads appeared, so naturally, I just increased them, but that didn't had any effect. Script will crash with " can't start new thread " exception.

So after alot of digging around here on stackoverflow, I found the idea to use threading.stack_size(), i also read the docs on python regarding that.
So I went ahead and did this:

```
threading.stack_size(64*1024)
```

The problem is that, it has no effect. I still can not produce more than 700 threads, even though enough ram is free ( close to 2.4GB )

Here is a part of the code where it fits in, for better understanding .

```
class Downloader(threading.Thread):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def run(self):
        while True:
            host,user,page= self.queue.get()
            self.checker(host,user,page)
            self.queue.task_done()
            threading.stack_size(64*1024)
```

After hours and hours of searching about the issue, single solution I came to was to recompile python all together and edit that part about the stack size. That option is wa above me, and I am pretty sure there is another elegant solution to my problems.

I've checked Res Monitor, and there's plenty of stand-by memory for use available, idle memory as well.
It simply refuses to go pass the 700 marker.
Am I using the stack_size() wrong?
Please do not advice me to use Twisted / asyncore !

From what I understand, it has something to do with the virtual space assignment also. Any chance / solution that could help me increase thread numbers, given that there's plenty of RAM to go around ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The problem here is not a design that limits you to 700 threads, but thinking that being able to create more (or even nearly that many) was going to be useful.

Comment: That isn't really helping my problem, and is a little over the topic. If I wouldn't need to have so many, I wouldn't bother spending hours and days over the issue, would I now ? I don't mean to be disrespectful, but I came here for help, not for a redesign of code. I do appreciate the heads up though.

Comment: I wrote it as a comment, not an answer, for the simple reason that it *is* a comment, not an answer to the question you asked. I honestly hope somebody can give you a direct answer to your question -- but if they do, I have some doubt about how helpful it's really likely to be.

Comment: @IchabodCrane: since I really doubt you have a 700-core machine running Python, most of your threads will be executing sequentially, with the added overhead of the continuous context change and GIL lock/unlock/wait (which, by the way, unless your code is IO-bound, kills parallelism on its own) so Jerry Coffin's observation is spot-on. You are most probably wasting your time on a lost cause. This smells a lot like a XY-problem, you should explain what is the *actual problem you are trying to solve*, there's surely a better way to solve it rather than using 700 threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need that many threads.  I understand you believe that you do, but - no, you don't ;-)

That said, the way you're calling `stack_size()` has no effect.  You can't change the stack size *after* the thread is created, you have to change it *before* threads are created.  So move this:

```
    threading.stack_size(64*1024)
```

to module level, executed only once, and before you create any threads.  I don't know whether it will help, but that's the right way to do it, and the way you are doing it is futile.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I needed. I did the modifications, and it works out perfectly. Really appreciate the help !

Comment: You're welcome!  Now you should explain your real problem, so we can help you get rid of about 690 of those threads ;-)

Comment: The client simply wants more power out if the script. That is really the only problem, speed. And I do not know how to do this better than with threads. I read about asyncore / twisted, but I never found any example on how to use it with a function that takes argv , and which connects to a ton of sockets.